# Conger vs Partir

Tags: choix-de-mot, verbes

As I understand it, both of these mean "to leave" but there must be some subtle differences. Can anyone tell me what they are and when you would use one over the other?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One not subtle but major difference is that the verb *conger* doesn't exist...

I guess you are thinking about the expression *[prendre congé](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/prendre_cong%C3%A9) de ...* which is a formal way to say *dire au revoir et quitter quelqu'un*. e.g.:

> *Je dois partir.* (I have to go)

> *Je dois vous quitter.* (I have to leave you)

> *Je dois prendre congé de vous.* (I have to [take leave](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+your+leave) of you)

Unlike *quitter*, *prendre congé* is almost only used when referring to people leaving other people.

Comment: Although this answer is fine, I think it might be improved in adding nuance : I don't think "partir" and "prendre congé" are freely interchangeable. My guess would be that "partir" has a broader scope and convey the meaning of "going from somewhere" while "prendre congé" can only be employed in "(temporarily) being absent from somewhere". E.g. I don't think "le train prend congé à 13h" would fit well.

Comment: @JeremyGrand *Le train prend congé à 13 h* is indeed not idiomatic at all. Answer updated to make clear *prendre congé* scope is narrower.

Comment: The English equivalent of _prendre congé_ would be [_to take your leave_](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+your+leave) which is also formal and bordering on the archaic.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for the link, answer updated..

Comment: as a side note, 'Congé' is also used for time off / holidays, but this is quite old French. I was born in 1972 and spent my kid years in France. The word 'congé' already sounded old at the time.

Comment: @Thomas I don't think *congé* is that outdated. *Poser des congés* or *prendre ses congés* is still largely used nowadays.

Comment: could it be more regional? my parents were living in the East (Alsace), near Germany, and I never heard people use it, but in the West (Normandy) it was quite common. I noticed other words like this ('A tantôt' for example); but then again I haven't been in France for decades so maybe it was just my isolated experience.

Comment: @Thomas I'm not aware of regional differences. Do you remember what alternative was used?

Comment: In my family they would always talk about ‘vacances’ (holidays) which doesn’t have exactly the same meaning, just some overlap.

Comment: @Thomas Oui, les congés payés et les vacances payées, ce n'est pas la même chose ;-)

Comment: quelle est la difference?

Comment: *Congés payés* est un terme officiel et courant qui indique que l'on continue à être rémunéré par son employeur un nombre de jours définis durant lesquels on ne travaille pas. *Vacances payées* est moins courant et peut avoir plusieurs sens. J'aurais tendance à comprendre qu'il s'agit plus du prix des vacances elles-mêmes que de la rémunération durant la période, [exemple](https://changethework.com/vacances-payees-salaries/). On peut aussi poser des congés mais ne pas prendre de vacances, ou à l'inverse partir en vacances en ayant posé des RTT qui ne sont techniquement pas des jours de CP.

Answer (score 3):

No natif speaker but the verb '*conger*' does not exist as far as I know.
You can find information about the word '*congé*' (I guess you confused the noun 'congé' with the possible past participle of the fictitious "verb" '*conger*' which as I said does not exist) below:

- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cong%C3%A9#French;
- https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cong%C3%A9;
- https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cong%C3%A9

Analyzing the usage of *partir* goes beyond the scope of a simple FSE's answer. The only possible related construction that I can think of is

> *prendre congé* : Faire les adieux qu’exige la politesse avant de partir.

See, for instance, https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/prendre_cong%C3%A9

There is also the related verb **[congédier](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/cong%C3%A9dier/18176)**.